# Unable to recieve value of getquery parameter in Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link

I have to add an extra parameter as "meetingToken" in firebase deeplink .

But On adding an extra parameter "meetingtoken" as queryparameter im not recieving the value and getting error in joinmeeting(it) : No value passed for parameter meetingToken.

While the same works fine on passing a single parameter, What changes do i need to recieve both the parameters value.

Currently its giving me error at:

```
 deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode")?.let { joinMeeting(it) }
```

No value passed for parameter 'meetingToken'

Link = https://example.in/?meetingCode=myuser?meetingToken=rtgdhh.tywufgsioqpp

```
private fun handleDynamicLink() {
    Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            val deepLink: Uri?
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link

on android debugging its generating the following firebase Link = https://example.in/?meetingCode=userroom?meetingToken%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1Ni

                deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingToken")
                deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode")?.let { joinMeeting(it) }


            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { _ ->
            toast(getString(R.string.main_error_fetch_dynamic_link))
        }
}



 private fun joinMeeting (meetingCode:String, meetingToken:String) {
    MeetingUtils.startMeeting(
        this, meetingCode,
    meetingToken)


}
```

meeting Utils.kt file to start meeting

```
object MeetingUtils {


fun startMeeting(context: Context,  meetingCode: String, meetingToken: String)
```

app deep link url string

```
<string name="app_deep_link_url">https://example.in/?meetingCode=%1$s?meetingToken=%2$s</string>
```

this is the share code

```
    private fun onShareMeetingCodeClick() {
    tilCodeCreateMeeting.setEndIconOnClickListener {

            binding.tilCodeCreateMeeting.error = null
            toast(getString(R.string.main_creating_dynamic_link))

            Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync {
                link = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_deep_link_url, getCreateMeetingCode(), getCreateMeetingToken() ))
                domainUriPrefix = getString(R.string.app_dynamic_link_url_prefix)
                androidParameters {}
                navigationInfoParameters {
                    forcedRedirectEnabled = true // Directly open the link in the app
                }
            }.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                val shortDynamicLink = result.shortLink.toString()
                startShareTextIntent(
                    getString(R.string.main_share_meeting_code_title),
                    getString(R.string.main_share_meeting_code_desc, shortDynamicLink)
                )
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                toast(getString(R.string.main_error_create_dynamic_link))
            }
```

Can Someone guide me how to recieve value of getQueryparameter for more than 1 parameter. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&` instead of `?` on appending the second parameter on your deep link. Also, the deep link configured should be URL-encoded since multiple parameters are configured in the deep link. Your sample deep link should look like this.

```
link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.in%2F%3FmeetingCode%3Dmyuser%26meetingToken%3Drtgdhh.tywufgsioqpp
```

By URL-encoding the deep link, FDL will able to distinguish which parameters belongs to the deep link.

> ```kotlin
> Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_deep_link_url, getCreateMeetingCode(), getCreateMeetingToken()))
> ```

I'm not sure on what you're trying to achieve passing multiple parameters on getString for the deep link value.

Won't it make sense to create a `StringBuilder` or append it manually?

```kotlin
val deepLink = getString(R.string.app_deep_link_url)+ "%2F%3FmeetingCode%3D$meetingCode%26meetingToken%3D$meetingToken";
link = Uri.parse(deepLink);
```

where "app_deep_link_url" in strings.xml is

```
<string name="app_deep_link_url">https%3A%2F%2Fexample.in</string>
```

Comment: I tried this but it shows syntax error.
? (`<string name="app_deep_link_url">https://modimeet.in/?meetingCode=%1$s&meetingToken=%2$s</string>`?)


Also as im new to kotlin i have doubt here:

? (` .let { joinMeeting(it) }`?) 


because its showing error on (it) No value pass for meetingToken

Comment: Is there a way we can pair them in 1 

? (`deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode",  "meetingToken")`?)

So it will able to distinguish it  .let { joinMeeting(it)

Comment: I'm not sure on what you're trying to achieve passing multiple parameters on getString for the deep link value.
`Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_deep_link_url, getCreateMeetingCode(), getCreateMeetingToken()))`

Won't it make sense to create a [StringBuilder](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-string-builder/) or append it manually?

Comment: You can append it manually with

```kotlin
val deepLink = getString(R.string.app_deep_link_url)+ "%2F%3FmeetingCode%3D$meetingCode%26meetingToken%3D$meetingToken";
link = Uri.parse(deepLink);
```

where "app_deep_link_url" is
`<string name="app_deep_link_url">https%3A%2F%2Fexample.in</string>`

Comment: Actually its a meeting app we need roomcode & roomtoken to enter. Whenever anyone create a new meeting. the following code will generate a long link for  room & token for the meeting:
? (`link = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_deep_link_url, getCreateMeetingCode(),  getCreateMeetingToken() ))`?)


and later the firebase short link we can send for invite to other user:

domain.page.link/arsshshsj

When anyone clicks on the above link then this firebase code will be executed:
? (`deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode")?.let { joinMeeting(it) }`?)

So that we can start >>

Comment: So that we can start a function to execute meeting:

? (`private fun joinMeeting (meetingCode:String, meetingToken:String) {
        MeetingUtils.startMeeting(
            this, meetingCode,
            meetingToken)


    }`?)

The issue is previously its working fine with 1 parameter meetingcode. after adding the meetingtoken parameter its giving issue at ?.let { joinMeeting(it)